# How can I integrate yepnope.js with Wordpress (and plugins)?

Tags: javascript, performance

To improve my website's loading speed a bit (and to impress the judges--sad reality of the kind of website I'm building, there are judges), I want to implement yepnope.js to load the Javascript dynamically. However, I'm running into a roadblock with the Wordpress jQuery plugins, because Wordpress still embeds them as a script tag.

Is there a way to modify Wordpress's script-loading mechanism so that I can just get an array of plugins to feed into Yepnope, or some other solution?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could use `wp dequeue script` and then use yepnode, but honestly I don't see the point with regards to speed since `wp_enqueue_script` already allows for conditional loading with dependencies.

This is assuming your using well written theme/plugins that allow for the use of the built in function hooks. You can get an array of plugins but you cannot guess how  plugin/theme authors  are loading scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Using yepnope is going to cause too much trouble.  Just use what WordPress already provides.  Add some conditional scripting references with the `is_admin()` and plugin specific pages.

I would use `wp_dequeue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_script()` appropriately combined with some WP minify, since yepnope is a way to speed up the site to begin with.

#### References

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-minify/
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script